# Firebase user.getDisplayName() returns null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add a user using the Firebase auth and it returns the displayName as null, even though it asks for it via the UI on sign up. Any ideas why and how to fix? When I logout and then Login to the app with the same credentials, the Display name is visible.

Also attached the Screenshots:

[image: When registering for the first time]

[image: When logging in again with same credentials]

**Here's the code I am using to do this:**

```
private void userProfile(){
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if(user != null){
        UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdate = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                .setDisplayName(editTextName.getText().toString().trim()).build();

        user.updateProfile(profileUpdate).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d("Testing", "User Profile Updated");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**I am displaying it on the next Activity using the following code:**

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
textViewUserName.setText("Welcome "+ user.getDisplayName());
```

The code works for user.getEmail() and other parameters provided by Firebase but not user.getDisplayName()

Answer (score 3):

In my case I am using this way, I hope will help for you.

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
    // User is Login            
    String displayName = user.getDisplayName();

    // If the above were null, iterate the provider data
    // and set with the first non null data
    for (UserInfo userInfo : user.getProviderData()) {
        if (displayName == null && userInfo.getDisplayName() != null) {
            displayName = userInfo.getDisplayName();
        }
    }

    textViewUserName.setText("Welcome "+ displayName);
    }
```

Comment: ain't working mate. Still has the same issue

Comment: This code only fetches the display name using social profile (google/fb). After this you need to update the user's display name once. Following that, getDisplayName() will return the right info.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, its caused because like you said at the first time logging in it does not finish the login functions before you ask for the display name..

My solution was to put all the getting the name function in postDelay so it'll have time to finish initializing the login so you could fetch the name.

Try this -

```
textViewUserName.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            textViewUserName.setText("Welcome "+ user.getDisplayName());
        }
    },1000);
```

Let me know if it worked.

**Update -**
Another solution in result of the first one not fixing it -

Save the name with shared preferences at the register function at the register activity and then pull it from your main activity.

make yourself a PrefsManager class -

```
public class PrefsManager {
  public static void setCurrentUserName(String name){
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(CURRENT_USER_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
      editor.putString("name", userName);
      editor.apply();
  }

  public static String getCurrentUserName(){
      SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(CURRENT_USER_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
      if (prefs.getString("name", null) != null) {
      String name = prefs.getString("name", "");//The empty "" is for default value.
      return name;
  }
}
```

Then at the register function save it -

```
PrefsManager.setCurrentUserName(name)
```

And at the MainActivity function pull it back -

```
textViewUserName.setText("Welcome "+ PrefsManager.getCurrentUserName());
```

Hope this works but keep in mind you have to keep track that always the value in the shared preferences will be up to date, that means once you logout put an empty value in it and while login in/new register insert the current user's value.

This is a sort of a walk around for fixing this issue.
Let me know if managed to make it work.

Comment: mate this code also does not work.

Comment: See the second solution i just updated in the answer. Let me know how it works

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: Did you initialize the prefs builder in the onCreate like showed in the lib docs? (the link i added) @JatinBhatia

Comment: Never mind i deleted the use of the easyprefs library from my solution. Try if now. @JatinBhatia